# Is it easier/more reliable to install a Windows partition over Ubuntu; or backup, install Windows fully then install an Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot

I'm starting an [Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk/) Maths degree soon. I'm being sent [Mathcad](http://www.ptc.com/product/mathcad/) as part of the course. It relies on .NET so [doesn't seem to work in Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10538&iTestingId=19959). I'm therefore going to buy Windows 7 and dual boot.

I understand installing Windows isn't as user-friendly as installing Ubuntu so, to try and preserve my sanity, I wanted to know which approach is easier to get working:

1. Keep my Ubuntu 12.04 system and install a Windows 7 partition using the Windows 7 disk; or
2. Install Windows 7, wiping Ubuntu in the process, then install an Ubuntu 12.04 partition using a Live CD and restore from a backup?

Comment: If your system is up to par, use VMWare or VirtualBox.

Comment: Alas my processor doesn't support virtualization.

Comment: @GarryCairns You might be surprised. Virtualization solutions existed well before any part of them were implemented in hardware. If you're having trouble getting virtualization to work on your system, you might have to use an earlier version of your virtualization software, or different software. If you wish to pursue this as a possible solution, I'd suggest posting a new question about it (search first).

Comment: Thanks Eliah. I may post a question even if I do find the answer myself, then answer it to get an answer on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although possible, it isn't advisable to install Windows side by side an already installed Linux OS. Windows may destroy your Linux partition if you are not careful to specify a separate partition when running the installer. And Windows will definitely destroy GRUB (your boot manager). To be safe, I would install Windows first, then install Ubuntu. In other words, option 2.

Also, virtualization extensions [aren't a requirement for Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html) if you wanted to go the virtualization route, they are just recommended and provide performance enhancements.

Comment: Is this new? I've successfully resized linux partitions leaving space at the front which windows has seen with no problem.

Comment: @Elfy - This has always been the safe way to do it since I've been using Linux (early 2000's). Unless Windows became more open and respectful of other operating systems recently, I would continue installing Windows first, then Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if Windows installation replaces GRUB in MBR. 
You can always add a "boot sector loader" to Windows 7 boot manager and boot Linux/Unix from Windows.

See [here](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) how to dual boot Windows 7 with any Linux or Unix descendant like Fedora, Ubuntu or FreeBSD for example.