# Install dual-boot Win7 alongside existing Ubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, windows, system-installation, uninstall

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my laptop and I would like to install Windows 7 home premium *without* uninstalling Ubuntu. If this is not possible, is it possible to do a full backup to an iso file and then reinstall Ubuntu with all of my programs still there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

### Don't do it.

If you have the option, you should [install linux first before windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313623/install-linux-first-before-windows). Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/165264/89515) if you need more convincing about not doing this. The problems compound if you are using encrypted LVM.

### Install Windows First

This has the advantage of GRUB detecting your Windows installation and allowing you the [dual-boot](/questions/tagged/dual-boot) option.  You can also have Windows manage your Ubuntu installation by using a program called **Wubi**.

These Q&A are probably your best introduction to Wubi:

- [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)
- [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

### Creating your backup

The Official Documentation has a [great primer on doing a backup](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/backup-why.html).  Whereas this link details the [important file locations](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/backup-thinkabout.html) that you'll want to pay attention to, namely:

> Personal files (documents, music, photos and videos) [...] consider backing up the entire Home folder.